# Symfony2 merge documents to PDF

Tags: symfony

I need to merge various PDF and Excel documents in one PDF. For example I have:
 - A.pdf
 - B.pdf
 - D.xlsx
 - E.doc

Whats I need is to merge all 4 documents content to a one result.pdf document.

There is any bundle/library to achieve that? or maybe the best option is to create a python script and call it from symfony2 (how?) to generate that pdf?

Any help or clue?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Symfony provides a Process component that wraps nicely wraps around the native php exec/system functions.

Check it out on: https://github.com/symfony/Process

Another option would be to use the PDF Component from Zend Framework. I'm not sure if it allows merging of PDF's but it should only be a matter of reading through the documentation to find out.

Check out this tutorial about ZendPDF in symfony: http://www.craftitonline.com/2011/06/pdf-generation-with-symfony2-part-ii-zend-option/

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

The @DucTa's dead link was talking about `pdftk`, a binary with which you can merge multiple PDF documents.

Download it on your server using `apt-get install pdftk`.

For now, I think it doesn't exist any bundle using pdftk, but you can use something like `exec()` or `passthru()` to do the trick.

Example :

```
exec('pdftk doc1.pdf doc2.pdf doc3.pdf output merged.pdf');
```